# Assembly Language: Completing the program to get the midstring

Tags: string, assembly, x86, x86-16, dos

```
.model small
.stack
.data
       msg1 db "Enter string max of 9 characters: $"
       msg2 db 13,10, "Enter a number: $"
       msg3 db 13,10, "Midstring: $"

strNine db "$"
num db 0,"$"
mid db "$"

varName label byte
maxL db 10
actL db 0
actCont db 10 dup("?")

.code
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax

      ;-------------------- Input String ---------------------
        mov ah,9
        lea dx,msg1
        int 21h

        mov ah,0ah
        int 21h

        mov strNine,al
        mov bh,strNine

       ;-------------------- Number ---------------------
       mov ah,9
       lea dx,msg2
       int 21h

       mov ah,1
       int 21h

       mov num,al
       mov bl,num

       ;-------------------- Midstring ---------------------
       mov ah,9
       lea dx,msg3
       int 21h


mov ah,4ch
int 21h
 END
```

I need to find the midstring and I'm stuck since I'm new to Assembly Language.

Expected behaviour:

```
Enter max of 9 String: helloword
Enter a number: 3
Midstring: lloword
```

The leading space, the h and e shall be deleted because of the number input by the user.

The only part the I've gotten is to get the input from the user which is the string and number which i have saved in the BX memory which is used for indexing

I just need some tips/guides from you guys to finish the program.

Comment: SO isn't the right place for asking for guides, but http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info does have lots of links to docs and guides.  tip: check the docs for the system calls you're using.  Pretty sure the DOS read-string function needs a pointer to a buffer.  I doubt your current program could even print the whole string.  Trailing substrings are trivial in strings terminated by a special character: just pass a pointer to the start point, and it still ends in the same place.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. Sorry to ask for tips or guides. Im just really confuse right now on how to use the registers and the hex codes.

Comment: If you mean ah=code DOS system calls, check the DOS interrupt list for docs on what system call does what.  The middle-of-string problem is just pointer math.

Comment: *I just need some tips/guides from you guys* I see you got those tips. How did it work out?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov ah,9
> lea dx,msg1
> int 21h
> mov ah,0ah
> int 21h
> ```

How can this input work at all? At the moment that you call the DOS input function your DX register is still set for the *msg1* when it should be set to point to the *varName* input structure.

---

> ```
> mov ah,0ah
> int 21h
> mov strNine,al
> mov bh,strNine
> ```

What do you expect the AL register to hold at this point? This DOS function doesn't store a useful value there!